# Select statement not checking num_rows correctly

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am making a simple PHP and MySQL IP banning script and I am at the stage of checking to see if the IP address is already banned. I have created a test file called `test.php` and this is its contents:

```
<?php
require_once('../includes/db_connect.php');
session_start();

$ip = '1.1.1';
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `ip`, `reason` FROM `banned_ips` WHERE `ip` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $ip);
$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    header('Location: banned.php');
}

$stmt->close();

 ?>

 <html>
 <h1>This is a test page</h1>
 </html>
```

As you can see I have set the `$ip` variable equal to `1.1.1` which is a test value that does exist in the database, therefore should be seen as banned, however it doesn't see it as being banned and therefore doesn't redirect to the banned page.

Am I doing something wrong when checking to see if the IP address already exists in the database?

My database structure is as follows:

Table: `banned_ips`
column 1: `id`
Column 2: `ip`
column 3: `reason`

EDIT: Sorry for the typo, I do have an IP column and it is a varchar.

Comment: *"My database structure is as follows: Table: banned_ips column 1: `id` column 2: `reason`"* --- *Stupid question alert* => You do have a column named `ip` right?

Comment: It seems like you may have made a typo in your question in regards to `column 1: id` which should have read as `column 1: ip` --- Your answer lies below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might get it to work: (if you have ip column as a varchar in the db)

```
<?php
require_once('../includes/db_connect.php');
session_start();

$ip = '1.1.1';
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `ip`, `reason` FROM `banned_ips` WHERE `ip` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $ip);
$stmt->execute();

//Transfers a result set from the last query
$stmt->store_result(); 

if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    header('Location: banned.php');
}

$stmt->close();

 ?>

 <html>
 <h1>This is a test page</h1>
 </html>
```

Comment: Yep, this is answer. +1 -- an added explanation would be beneficial for the OP though.

Comment: Thank you this worked, and sorry for the typo, it was my mistake.